# GPU library to compute continuous 1-D wavelet transforms

Tags: library, signal-processing, gpu

I need to compute a large amount of continuous 1-D wavelet transforms (CWT). I'm looking for a GPU library to compute CWT. So far I have only found GPU libraries to compute *discrete*  wavelet transforms such as [GPUDWT](https://code.google.com/p/gpudwt/).

If possible:

- compatible with Nvidia GPUs
- open source
- Linux or Windows 7

Comment: I think you should probably link http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8009/using-continuous-verses-discrete-wavelet-transform-in-digital-applications or similar . . . because analogies with FFT /DFT versus "continuous" FT don't hold

Comment: that's a good reference to have.